# Access a Folder with json files on my App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I a have a Folder with json files and I add the following to my yaml file:

```
- url: /jsons
  static_dir: jsons
```

but when I try to Access the Folder I get the following error:

Error: Not Found
The requested URL /jsons/1038031602031405110202090000.json was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you embedding the link (the /jsons/....) within a file/page? If so, I suspect the 404 is due to the resolution of the full path (full url) - try typing the url directly within your browser and see what happens. If there is no issue, then it is due to the path resolution when embedded in a page. In such a case, you have to figure out the relative path

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing documentation about your issue, I found the following from [request handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_Requests):

**You can select the programming language and version below the title**

When App Engine receives a web request for your application, it calls the handler script that corresponds to the URL, as described in the application's [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) configuration file.

The Python 2.7 runtime supports the WSGI standard and the CGI standard for backwards compatibility. WSGI is preferred, and some features of Python 2.7 do not work without it. The configuration of your application's script handlers determines whether a request is handled using WSGI or CGI.

As a result, you should read the tutorial [Getting Started with Flask on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env).

In that case, the recommended handler is:

```
handlers: - url: /.* script: main.app
```

Reviewing more about the error message you are getting and as the last comment, the error message code that you probably have is 404 (Not Found):

The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
A 404 status code does not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or permanent.

**Please note that: Python 2 is no longer supported by the community.
We recommend that you migrate Python 2 apps to Python 3.**